# Static AdView size before loading Ads

Tags: android, android-studio, google-ads-api

I am on a new App and in that I want to show some ads on the bottom. The `AdView` however is height 0dp at app startup and inflates only when the ads are loaded and then resizes the fragment and moves its content and children, which I want to avoid obviously.

My app is build like following:

[image]

In my MainActivity view I have a `ConstraintLayout` which has the `Toolbar`, the fragment container and the `AdView` as children and it's arranged like in the screenshot above.
So the container is between the `AdView` and `Toolbar` which is causing the problem.

Of course I can make the fragment container align to the bottom of its parent but then the ads are shown above the containers content which can cause problems on smaller screens.

Is there any way I can somehow "reserve" the `AdView`s size upon app startup or something like this?

Comment: try 48dp minimumHeight

Comment: @Hooman Thank you, you brought me to the idea that I could google the sizes of the different ``adSize``s and hardcode it. Yet, I did not like this too much since hardcoding is a bad practice in general. However while googling for the sizes, I saw that there is the option of ``Adaptive Banners`` and checked it out [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive). My new idea now is to calculate the banners size according to the screen size and set it programmatically before loading of the ads.

Comment: Unfortunately, my approach with ``Adaptive Banner`` ``adSize`` does not work as intended. The ``AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(Context, Width)`` returns an ``AdSize`` object which ``getHeight()`` method returns ``0dp``. My next approach will be over the ``Smart Banner`` ``AdSize`` like [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/smart). This provides 3 different heights depending on the screen width. So I make 3 xml files for the 3 sizes and hardcode the ``AdView`` height like @Hooman suggested above.